Kotlin multiplatform library publishing. Can't use classes in commonMain
I have created a pure Kmm library without using platform-specific functions. all the code is in commonMain only. It's simple class:
class TemperatureConverter {
    fun celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius: Double): Double {
        return celsius * 1.8 + 32.0
    }

    fun fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit: Double): Double {
        return (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }

    val simpleString : String = "SimpleString"

}

I am publishing this library to mavenLocal. In the folder .m2 I see a published aar artifact and a pom file. I also see all the platforms that are listed in the targets. Here is an example of build.gradle.kts of the whole kmm library project:
plugins {
    id("com.android.library").version("8.0.2").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.24").apply(false)
    id("maven-publish")
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("release") {
                groupId = "com.ag.secondTry"
                artifactId = "test-lib-second"
                version = "1.0.13"
                artifact("C:\\KotlinSamples\\KotlinLibs\\TestLib\\sharedMpTest\\build\\outputs\\aar\\sharedMpTest-debug.aar")
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}

next is the example build.gradle.kts shared module of kmm library:
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("maven-publish")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()

    androidTarget {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }
    androidTarget()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        framework {
            baseName = "sharedMpTest"
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ag.kmmtestlib"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

in another multiplatform project, I connect this library to a shared module and cannot use My class TemperatureConverter in commonMain. it is only available in androidMain. what should I do to make this class available in commonMain?
if I remove artifact from the build.gradle.kts, the library will not appear in the external libraries of the project to which I am connecting it.
